# How to add an icon from the android library to my project using ADT

Tags: android, adt, android-icons

Android has several system icons available, such as [these](http://androiddrawables.com/status.html).

I can't use them in my application (for system notifications as an example) since they are not made public within the API. So I would like to add them to my project in eclipse using ADT.

Is there a way to do this automatically? For example, when I start a new android project, it allows me to create an icon for my project, and creates it in all sizes and places them in the correct resource folders. I'd like to import other icons from the android library the same way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what it says [here](http://androiddrawableexplorer.appspot.com/):

> NOTE: Some of the images in the Android jar are not public and
>   therefore cannot be directly used (you can copy them to you own
>   application, but can't reference them via the "android" package
>   namespace). This project does *not* distinguish between what is public
>   and what is not. If you try to use an image that is not public, you
>   will get an error indicating that fact.

So it seems that the way to go is to copy the icons to your project, as Android won't allow direct access to them.

Comment: Yep, thats what I was trying to say in my post... The question was if ADT (the android plugin for eclipse) can automate that, like it does with the launcher icon. That will save me having to get different icon sizes and putting each one in the correct folder...